# learning mahout on windows

Tags: windows, mahout

I am familiar with machine learning algorithms, have good background in statistics and know how to program in R and Python. I have a Windows 7 PC with 4 gb RAM and 200 GB free hard disk space on my Lenovo t430 laptop. I want to learn/check/observe Apache Mahout algorithms and try examples. I am a paid member of safari online books and have access to books such as "Apache Mahout Cookbook" and "Mahout in Action"

Please answer my below questions.

```
1) what softwares do I need to install? are they available to install on a windows pc?
2) please provide a link to install those softwares on a windows pc
3) is there a book that will shows how to use Mahout on a windows pc?
```

I already searched stackexchange site as well as performed google search extensively, but I am still confused regarding which softwares to install, how to install them and how to run examples from mahout website. I am confused because some of the results that I got on Stackexchange site are 2 years old and I feel that they might not be valid any more. Also when I performed google search, variety of websites and youtube videos told me to install variety of softwares.

Comment: Questions asking us to locate or recommend tools, libraries or off-site resources are inappropriate here. See this [help/on-topic] page, particularly item #5 in the numbered list. Three of your four questions are asking for one of those items, and the other one (#3) is far too vague to be answered here.

Comment: Isn't it just a java lib? Like, I know nothing about it, but the link right on the website goes to folder with distributions that contain .jar files. I'm sure if I opened them in  eclipse or something it would expose the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

From the readme:

```
Welcome to Apache Mahout!

Mahout is a scalable machine learning library that implements many different
approaches to machine learning.  The project currently contains
implementations of algorithms for classification, clustering, frequent item
set mining, genetic programming and collaborative filtering.
```

Of course you can run Java and the Java SDK on windows. All you need is an IDE that you can code Java in, such as Eclipse or IntelliJ. Just load up the jars!

The distribution contains:

```
mahout-core.jar
mahout-examples.jar
mahout-integration.jar
mahout-math.jar
```

seems like pretty straightforward java library. You might need to toss in a Hadoop or a database or whatnot to do some of the examples.